# target children elements but not the ones of the clicked one

Tags: jquery

I've seen similar examples but can't figure out how to get "`not(this)`" working in my code.
Basically what I need to do is:
 **target children elements but not the ones of the clicked (`this`) one**

Here's what I've attempted:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("li").click(function(){
      jQuery(this).children('.step').slideToggle("slow");
      jQuery not(this).children('.step').slideUp("slow"); // any advice?...
   });
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your question?

Comment: A HTML code would clear the situation a lot

Comment: Sorry for not formatting the "not(this)" part properly. I hope it wasn't too confusing. The idea of the code is that when the user clicks a li, the child .step will slide down (revealing the corresponding content) while the child .step of other li slide up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.siblings()`

```
(function($){ // REMAP "$" to jQuery
$(function(){ // DOM READY shorthand
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).slideDown(800).siblings().slideUp(800);
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

or in your case might be this (I don't know as it's a bit unclear)

```
 $("li").click(function(){
     $(this).find('.step').slideToggle(800);
     $(this).siblings().find('.step').slideUp(800);
 });
```

<kbd>**[jQuery API Documentation - Siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**</kbd>